# UWP Change text inside a listview in XAML using binded boolean property

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp-xaml

I have a listview with a grid and elements inside. One is a textblock and I want to show a Segoe MDL2 icon if binded property is true, or another if it's false (named MListEntryControl). All examples I have read are for pre-UWP or didn't understand well how visualstatetriggers can be of use for this especific need. Thank you.

```
<ListView x:Name="MovementsList" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,12,0,0" IsItemClickEnabled="False" SelectionMode="None" MinHeight="40">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Name="MListProvider" Text="{Binding Company.Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,12,0" ></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Name="MListProduct" Text="{Binding Product.Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,12,0" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Name="MListTemp" Text="{Binding Temperature}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,12,0" Grid.Column="2"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="MListEntryControl" Grid.Column="3"  FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="22" Text=""></TextBlock>
                                        <Button Click="DeleteMovement_Click" Tag="{Binding MovementId}" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                            <TextBlock Text="&#xE107;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="22"></TextBlock>
                                        </Button>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E0E4CC"/>
                                </Style>
                            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP Change text inside a listview in XAML using binded boolean property

For your scenario, I think the `DataTrigger` of  [XamlBehaviors](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors) package is suite for you and may be easier. When the binding data updated can trigger a `ChangePropertyAction`. You can reference the `DataTrigger` sample [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/blob/master/samples/CS/XAMLBehaviorsSample/DataTriggerControl.xaml).

For example, if the boolean property named "trueorfalse", code sample as follows:

```
<TextBlock
   x:Name="MListEntryControl"
   Grid.Column="3"                           
   FontSize="22"                        
   Text="&#xE107;">        
   <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior
                                Binding="{Binding trueorfalse}"
                               Value="true"  ComparisonCondition="Equal">
                                <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction
                                    PropertyName="FontFamily"
                                    TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=MListEntryControl}"
                                    Value="Segoe MDL2 Assets" />
                            </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>
                            <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior
                                Binding="{Binding trueorfalse}"
                               Value="false"  ComparisonCondition="Equal">
                                <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction
                                    PropertyName="FontFamily"
                                    TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=MListEntryControl}"
                                    Value="Yu Gothic UI" />
                            </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>
                        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors> 
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. To make it a bit more complete for future references:
Import Behaviors from Package Manager Console
Install-Package Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed
and   add this to the .xaml xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" xmlns:Interactions="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"